# Why's my FreeBSD OpenJDK port update failing (and how do I fix it)?

Tags: freebsd, bsd-ports

Makes good progress for the first half hour or so, then dies at:

```
cd bsd_amd64_compiler2/product && ./test_gamma
Using java runtime at: /usr/local/openjdk7/jre
Error occurred during initialization of VM
java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/invoke/AdapterMethodHandle
gmake[4]: *** [product] Error 1
gmake[4]: Leaving directory `/usr/ports/java/openjdk7/work/openjdk/build/bsd-amd64/hotspot/outputdir'
gmake[3]: *** [generic_build2] Error 2
gmake[3]: Leaving directory `/usr/ports/java/openjdk7/work/openjdk/hotspot/make'
gmake[2]: *** [product] Error 2
gmake[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/ports/java/openjdk7/work/openjdk/hotspot/make'
gmake[1]: *** [hotspot-build] Error 2
gmake[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/ports/java/openjdk7/work/openjdk'
gmake: *** [build_product_image] Error 2
*** [do-build] Error code 1
```

I'm really at a loss.  Previous versions built fine.  Doing my updates via the portsnap fetch/update then portmaster -a path.  OpenJDK, Apache, and Ruby are the only updates of note this time around.  Searching only came up with a couple hits (of the "oh, this is broke" followed by "oh it works now" with no explanation on *how* it was made to work)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the exact same problem when updating my ports tree.
I could fix this by completely de-installing the existing openjdk port and re-installing it again.
It looks like the openjdk port does not compile properly when there is already an jdk installed during compile time.

```
pkg delete '*jdk*' '*java*'
cd /usr/ports/java/openjdk7 && make install clean
```

Comment: "pkg delete" wouldn't do the removal due to dependencies, but "make deinstall" followed by a "make install clean" worked.